# How to fix error in folder android from flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

[image]

Detail problem:

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.

```
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 
'C:\Users\ADEITY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\d146c9752a26f79b52047fb6dc6ed385d064e120494f96f08ca63a317c41f94c.gradle' (C:\Users\Adeitya RH\.gradle\caches\7.4.2\scripts\7s4n1zerenary6wu67e7f3xej).
Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\ADEITY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\d146c9752a26f79b52047fb6dc6ed385d064e120494f96f08ca63a317c41f94c.gradle'.
startup failed:
General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 63
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
```

Comment: What JDK are you using?

Comment: I use 19.0.2 version

Comment: @CharlieAbouMoussa 19.0.2

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.